# Why is this happing in final render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

Hello respectable blenderes, I need your help to figure out why this is happening in my final render and how to avoid it. Since an image is worth hundreds of words I'll just drop it below, also https://we.tl/t-D5YfeQYdbh here's the link to the project, in case you need to see the settings. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Don't worry ... those are newly released Starlink satellites ... For Atmosphere object increase Subdivision to 3 or change a bit Scale (there is probably some conflict with Clouds object) ... Z-fight or what ever :)

Comment: Hello, increasing the subdivision value or changing to adaptive subdivision (in my case) did the trick :) thank you @vklidu